# mysql [Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns] ERROR

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-csv, utf8mb4

my text file is like this.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1faW_OkO7_VoEQL_gndFIOrJv2e4Ycuzo

and my table is here.

```
CREATE TABLE news(
    num INT auto_increment primary key,
    link VARCHAR(150),
    date INT,
    title VARCHAR(150) unique,
    description TEXT 
);
```

i try

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
    INTO TABLE news
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ', ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\n' (link, date, title, description);
```

but it not working what is my mistake?

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya  oh... how can i start at (link , date, title, description) ? num is auto_increment field so i don't want write it at my text

Comment: could be you need mediumtext ..  or more

Comment: @scaisEdge  it same results that i use 'LONGTEXT' type on description..

Comment: @sangoh what is your MySQL version ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  my version is 8.0.12  thanks.

Comment: @sangoh you have double quotes within the string for `description` . eg: `"description": "과기`
While you are mentioning to optionally enclose by `'"'`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks! it is  my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file has four columns looking like this

```
url,month,title,"description": data
```

A CSV import will include the word `"description":` at the beginning of each description column.

So remove `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` from your command, and you should be all set.

By the way, make sure your table definition mentions the `utf8mb4` character set (or some characters from your input may not get represented correctly). For best results, don't rely on the server defaults to choose character set.

```
CREATE TABLE news(
            num INT auto_increment primary key,
           link VARCHAR(150),
           date INT,
           title VARCHAR(150) unique,
    description TEXT 
)
COLLATE 'utfmb4_general_ci';
```

Comment: "description":  is my fault. i will remove this.!! thanks. i'm normalization description 
field with no special character so  utfmb4 don't need to me!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of Optionally Enclosed by `'`. I have faced the same issue before and got resolved it by making a simple adjustment.
Just use the Enclosed by clause immediately after 'Fields' keyword.
Hence your code would be like something:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
INTO TABLE news
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ', ' 
LINES
TERMINATED BY '\n' (link, date, title, description);
```